# jQuery onClick Image Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when you click on an image, it will do a function inside the document.

Now I am having a bit of trouble and I'm sure this is some stupid mistake but whats wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=star&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    $i = 0;
    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        $("<img>").attr("src", item.preview.medium).attr("onclick", "").appendTo("#images");
        $i++;
    });
});
</script>
```

They display correctly, its just that the onclick event doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating elements with jquery.. so just use its methods

```
$("<img>")
    .attr("src", item.preview.medium)
    .click(function(){ showStream(index);})
    .appendTo("#images");
```

---

Or you use this syntax instead

```
$("<img>", {
    src: item.preview.medium,
    click: function(){showStream(index);}
}).appendTo("#images");
```

Comment: With my function how would I make it call my function showStream with the variable $i as the parameter? As you can see I use $i as a counter. I tried in the functions braces just showStream($i) but nothing works on click. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3023566 updated answer.. but you need to use `index` instead of `$i`  (*due to scope, otherwise all calls will use the last `$i`*)

Answer (score 5):

Give each of your image a class, like 'leImage'.

Create an event listener like this:

```
$(".leImage").on("click", function()
{
    // Do stuff, get id of image perhaps?
    var id = this.id;
    // or
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

If this is not what you're asking for then you'll have to be more clear :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all set id for image.

```
<img src="../images/warning.png" id="imageId"/>
```

After that use this code:

```
<script>
    $('#imageId').click(function () {
        alert('It works!');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=star&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        $("<img>").attr("src", item.preview.medium).appendTo("#images");

    });
});


 $("#images img").on("click",function(e){
   alert("your function all")

  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name after on click is blank?

`$("#something").attr("onClick","new_function()");`